# How to install LunarVim on Windows?

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, plugin-system, lunarvim

I am installing LunarVim on Windows using the official docs available at: https://www.lunarvim.org/docs/installation

I run:

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lunarvim/lunarvim/master/utils/installer/install.sh)
```

in Admin PowerShell but it gives me an error:

```
The '<' operator is reserved for future use in PowerShell
```

and the installation doesn't proceed.

I have neovim installed but I don't think that has anything to do with this.

Any way to fix this?

**Update**: lunarvim.org now has separate Linux/MacOS and Windows versions of the installation command that you can check out on the link attached in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the instruction you followed are for a Unix shell.

I didn't install it myself but I believe you have to download and run the following powershell script on Windows: [install.ps1](https://github.com/LunarVim/LunarVim/blob/master/utils/installer/install.ps1)

In a powershell prompt you can run:

```
iwr -useb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LunarVim/LunarVim/master/utils/installer/install.ps1 | ni install.ps1

powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\install.ps1
```

Comment: I have selected `iwr` that `vim-plug` selected. I suppose it available by default on Windows `powershell`

Comment: Sort of. `iwr` _should_ be aliased to `Invoke-Webrequest`. But I can't verify the correctness of that command as I have never used it. Can't even say if the alias is guaranteed to be available (in any case, the full name of the cmdlet is preferable, but no need to get puritanical about a SE answer).

Comment: You are right, this was the case. Sadly, LunarVim (on the site docs) only has 1 Installation section without bifurcating Windows, Mac, and Linux devices. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are Welcome :-) Thanks for the feedback.